# How to create and host a SOAP web service in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, soap

It is possible create and host a SOAP web service in a Google App Engine, using Java?

I've been looking at the official GAE documentation and the internet, but I can't find information or instructions about it.

If possible, what are the libraries to add in the pom.xml and the configuration instructions for the application (for the web.xml and appengine-web.xml)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  The main thing to understand is that [AppEngine Java environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#enhancements_and_upgrades_in_the_java_8_runtime) uses Jetty HTTP/servlet container.  From there, you can follow the Metro [user guide](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/index.html) to add the web service to your site/application.  Metro is the JAX-WS implementation.  Here is what I did to add a SOAP web service to the GuessBook sample web site, which I ran in the local development environment - I was bit lazy and I didn't want to start from scratch:

1. Add the Metro dependency to your POM file:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
       <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create a standard SOAP web service class that will handle the incoming web service calls.  For example:

   ```
   package com.jh.guessbook;

   import javax.jws.WebService;
   import javax.jws.WebMethod;
   import javax.jws.WebParam;

   @WebService(serviceName = "SOAPHelloWorld")
   public class SOAPHelloWorld
   {
       /**
        * This is a sample web service operation
        */
       @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
       public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt)
       {
           return "Hello " + txt + " !";
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a `sun-jaxws.xml` file in your `WEB-INF` folder.  This is where you define your endpoints.  Here is the file for my sample web service:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <endpoints
           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
           version="2.0">
       <endpoint
               name="SOAPHelloWorld"
               implementation="com.jh.guessbook.SOAPHelloWorld"
               url-pattern="/soapws"/>
   </endpoints>
   ```
4. Last but not least, setup the WS listener, servlet, and URL mapping in the `web.xml`.  Here is what I added to my `web.xml`:

   ```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
         </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>SOAPHelloWorld</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
       </servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>SOAPHelloWorld</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/soapws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   ```

You can get the WSDL definition by browsing your endpoint with `?wsdl`.  In my case, again running locally, the URL is `http://localhost:8080/soapws?wsdl`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jose-henriquez . Your instructions worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, brilliant answer! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!